# How can I constrain a cell sum from over adding from a given value

Tags: excel-formula

Sat down for a small project that's supposed to count combat details for my tabletop gaming sessions during lunch, turns out the excel code hates me.

C8 = CREATURE MAX HP
D8 = CREATURE CURRENT HP
E8 = CREATURE DAMAGE HEALED
F8:L8 = PC1:PC8 DAMAGE CAUSED

My formula for adding these together is contained in cell D8 and looks like this:

```
=C8-SUM(F8:L8)+E8
```

But I don't want my cell to add higher than what's contained in C8. How can I keep that from happening?

Comment: Does min work for you? `=MIN(C8-SUM(F8:L8)+E8, C8)`

Comment: That's it. I was thinking MAX, but didn't think of using the MIN function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Does min work for you? =MIN(C8-SUM(F8:L8)+E8, C8) – Alexis Olson 8 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

I'll go ahead an make this into an answer.

You can approach this in a couple of ways. The first is using `MIN` which takes the lesser of the two arguments.

```
=MIN(C8-SUM(F8:L8)+E8, C8)
```

You could also use an `IF(test, result if true, result if false)` function.

```
=IF(C8-SUM(F8:L8)+E8 > C8, C8, C8-SUM(F8:L8)+E8)
```

or equivalently, pulling the `C8` value out, you have

```
=C8 + IF(E8 > SUM(F8:L8), 0, E8 - SUM(F8:L8))
```